# Javascript clickable dropdown from w3schools not working with jsfiddle. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Hey I hope someone comes by this and will be able to help me out or give me a few pointers.. This is a strange situation, I was looking for javascript code that would allow me to open a div once clicked then disappear if I click anywhere.

This is the code from w3schools.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now my intention was to use the js script and apply it to two different buttons that would have the same function.

You can view this example here. http://jz.xqlsv.com/ specifically the meet jessica button and therapies and services.

Now the meet jessica button works perfectly as the therapies and services one does not close when i click anywhere.. but you will notice that the css does change on the button but the div does not go away as the meet jessica button.

I have even tried to implement this script to jsfiddle, with the exact replica from w3schools. But it does not seem to work at all.

https://jsfiddle.net/tsatsurg/wz8tk8rq/9/

If anyone can help out with this I would greatly appreciate it.
The site is currently being developed in Wordpress if that helps at all.

Please take a look, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your fiddle, for several buttons, snippet (JS/CSS/HTML):

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var match = false, dropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (event.target.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {
      for (var c of dropdown.classList.values()) {
        if (c.indexOf('menu-') == 0 && event.target.classList.contains(c)) {
          match = true; break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (match) {dropdown.classList.add('show');
    } else {dropdown.classList.remove('show');}
  }
};
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}


/* Define menu positions */
.dropdown-content.menu-one {left: 0;}
.dropdown-content.menu-two {left: 144px;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn menu-one">Dropdown One</button>
  <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content menu-one">
    <a href="#">Link One 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link One 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link One 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="dropbtn menu-two">Dropdown Two</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content menu-two">
    <a href="#">Link Two 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link Two 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link Two 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly when uploading to jsfiddle.. one issue is that it will only close when you click again on the button. It does not close if you click anywhere else.

Comment: Then, I updated the answer, getting back to your `window.onclick` approach. You can check in your fiddle.

Comment: Thats awesome.. It works.. do you know if it will work for two buttons?
I am currently working on the code sent below.

Can you check out this https://jsfiddle.net/tsatsurg/avnmsLot/1/

Comment: I was going to comment on that. For more than one button you'll need to identify each case. Let me work a little bit on that and I may update the answer if I get a good solution.

Comment: I see, I have tried replicating your script as the one in the other example. But now the first button does not work... 

Please take a look at the JS example https://jsfiddle.net/tsatsurg/wz8tk8rq/33/

Now its funny, because if I remove the last script. It will turn the first button back on. (I am really unaware of why this is happening)

Your help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, updated for several buttons, as long as you define a common class to link a button to to a menu:

Answer (score 1):

You had several issues:

1. By adding a click event handler to the button AND the window, any click on the button will also trigger a click on the window because of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). So, one event will show the list and the next will hide it. To fix this, we need to cancel the event at the button click and [prevent it from bubbling upward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to the window.
2. Next, you were using JQuery, but in your Fiddle, you hadn't configured it to use that library.
3. You were using JQuery's `toggle()` method, not `toggleClass()`.
4. W3 Schools is not the best resource for modern, accurate information. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is better.

Take a look at [this modified Fiddle that works](https://jsfiddle.net/wbsojm4w/20/).

Comment: This is great information. Thank you. But I am looking to have two buttons working similarly.

Please take a look at the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/tsatsurg/avnmsLot/1/

Now everything seems to run properly. Except for the closing part.

When I click on the second button I expect the first to close, Instead it stays open. 

Can you please take a look and see what seems to be the issue?

Comment: @Digggid Rather than go through your code, I just updated mine by adding a second button. It shows the functionality you are looking for.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wbsojm4w/60/